# Firing a form submission before .focusout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a search form:

```
<form id="search" role="search" method="get" action="/">
    <input id="search-text" type="text" placeholder="Search" name="s">
    <input id="search-submit" type="submit" value="">
    <div id="search-toggle"></div>
</form>
```

That becomes visible when `#search-toggle` div is clicked — and hidden when `#search-text` input loses focus.

```
$( '#search-toggle' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( '#search input, .social' ).add( this ).toggle();
    $( '#search-text' ).focus();
});

$( '#search-text' ).focusout( function() {
    $( '#search-submit, #search-toggle, .social' ).add( this ).toggle();
});
```

If `#search-submit` button is clicked, how can I make sure the form is submitted before everything is hidden.

As it stands, the form submission never fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use little timeout before hiding form, so that submit event could propagate properly:

```
$('#search-text').focusout(function () {
    var self = this;
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#search-submit, #search-toggle, .social').add(self).toggle();
    }, 200);
});

$('#search').on('submit', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0c4s4kc1/